# Compress html as gzip instead of (pk)zip

Tags: python-2.7, gzip

I am trying to adapt a Python 2.7 routine for creating SQLite db dictionaries for an e-reader from TSV files.

The routine shown creates a (pk)zip file of an html string in lines 71-74 (# compress and save). I'd like the compressed file to be in gzip format instead. I'm really, really shaky on Python and I have been looking at examples of using gzip compression, trying to fit them into this routine (which I have already adapted in other ways for my own use from the original). I know that changes need to be made in line 9 (import) also, but am not sure which.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# by Jiri Orsag, 2014
# https://github.com/geoRG77/nook-dictionary
# Many thanks to Homeless Ghost for his script 'createRenateNSTdictionaryfromnookdictionarydb.py'
# which was a great source of ideas for my work

import sqlite3, sys, zipfile, zlib, os

# config
DICTIONARY_FILE = 'test.txt' # input file (needed)
OUTPUT_DB = 'ox_en_GB.db' # output file
TEMP_DIRECTORY = './temp/' # will be deleted after successful run
STEP = 10000 # for print message

########################################################

print 'Converting dictionary...'

con = sqlite3.connect(OUTPUT_DB)
con.text_factory = str
cur = con.cursor()

index = 0
duplicateCount = 1
prevTerm = ''

try:
  if not os.path.exists(TEMP_DIRECTORY):
    os.makedirs(TEMP_DIRECTORY)

  # open dict file
  dict = open(DICTIONARY_FILE, 'r')

  # delete previous tables
  cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS android_metadata')
  cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblWords')

  # create tables
  cur.execute('CREATE TABLE "android_metadata"("locale" TEXT)')
  cur.execute('CREATE TABLE "tblWords"("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "term" TEXT COLLATE nocase, "description" BLOB)')

  # convert dict to sql
  for line in dict:
    index += 1
    # uncomment next line to debug
    # print '# current line = %d' % index

    # split line
    data = line.split('\t')
    term = data.pop(0)

    # create HTML
    html = '<b>' + term + '</b>' + data[0].strip()

    # check for duplicates
    if term == prevTerm:
      duplicateCount += 1
      termEdited = term + '[' + str(duplicateCount) + ']'
    else:
      termEdited = term
      duplicateCount = 1

    # create html file
    term_stripped = termEdited.replace('/', '')
    temp_html = open(TEMP_DIRECTORY + term_stripped, 'wb')
    temp_html.write(html)
    temp_html.close()

    # compress & save
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile('_temp', mode='w')
    zf.write(TEMP_DIRECTORY + term_stripped)
    zf.close()

    # read & insert compressed data
    temp_compressed = open('_temp', 'rb')
    compressed = temp_compressed.read()
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO tblWords (_id, term, description) VALUES(?, ?, ?)', (index, termEdited, sqlite3.Binary(compressed)))

    # if duplicate then update previous row with [1]
    if duplicateCount == 2:
      cur.execute('UPDATE tblWords SET term="' + str(term + "[1]") + '" WHERE _id=' + str(index - 1) + '')

    os.remove(TEMP_DIRECTORY + term_stripped)
    prevTerm = term

    # print _id, term, description
    if ((index % STEP) == 0):
      print '# current line = %d' % index

    #if index == 100:
    #  break;

  # create term_index
  cur.execute('CREATE INDEX term_index on tblWords (term ASC)')
  cur.execute('SELECT * FROM tblWords order by _id LIMIT 10')

  dict.close
  # os.remove('_temp')
  # os.rmdir(TEMP_DIRECTORY)

except Exception, e:
  raise
else:
  pass
finally:
  pass

print 'Done. ' + str(index) + ' lines converted.'
```

Any hints or good references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import gzip` and replace `zipfile.ZipFile` with `gzip.open`. Write to the gzip file what you wrote to the temporary file, which is no longer necessary. E.g.

```
gz = gzip.open('_temp', mode='wb')
gz.write(html)
gz.close()
```

and get rid of the `temp_html` lines and the `os.remove()` of it. I recommend the `b` in the mode, which was missing for the zip file for some reason.

Comment: This does not work for me. There are two issues: 1) the gzip file has a compression ratio of 214%! and 2) the contents of the gzip file is literally: ./temp/advocar, where in this example the word to be looked up (i.e., the "term" in the routine) is "advocar". The contents should be the definition and other info which is the html string. Or maybe it's not, although that part has always worked fine with the (pk)zip so it's hard to see how that could have changed.

Comment: OK, I just checked that to be sure, restoring the zipfile.ZipFile part. That gives the correct content in the (pk)zip, a file called "advocar" which contains the definition. Compression ratio is still wonky, but not as bad at 100%.

Comment: Updated answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. This, at last (!), produces the correct content in the gzip file. The name of the string is "_temp" (as opposed to whatever "term" is), which is not ideal, but the content is correct. Compression ratio is still greater than 1 at 128%. I've seen compression values written into statements like this. I guess I need to try that next. A typical dictionary runs into the tens to hundreds of MB. I don't want that value to blow up.

Comment: The only way to get a compression ratio like that is if you are trying to compress very short strings. E.g., 100 bytes. What is the size of `html`?

Comment: Yes, I've read about that. Sort of like a small boat that's sinking and doesn't carry any ballast. Small files have almost nothing left to compress. A typical html file might be 400-500 bytes. Still, this clearly works to produce the needed gzip file. Now I just need to get the rest of it to work like the (pk)zip version did. I'm marking your answer as correct, which is certainly is for me. Thanks a lot!